# Hudson - Enable TLS for Emails on a Windows Service

Tags: email, windows-services, hudson, windows-server-2008, ssl

I have Hudson installed as a windows service on my server. I need to send emails over port 587 and I need TLS/SSL enabled. I saw that some people were able to get this to work on this forum post:

```
http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-2206
```

I am not sure how/where to apply that step to get it to work on a server running it as a windows service. Has anyone else resolved this? Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of hudson.xml, you will want to modify the "arguments" section to enable TLS:

```
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable="true" -jar "%BASE%\hudson.war" --httpPort=8080</arguments>
```

After making this change, you will need to re-install the service:

```
hudson.exe stop
hudson.exe uninstall
hudson.exe install
hudson.exe start
```

You will also want to make sure that "SSL" is **not** checked inside of "Manage Hudson" -> "Configure System"